# Blazor @inject data service depending on project

Tags: blazor-server-side

I have a shared .net 6 project for just controls. I wanted to use the same controls in .Net Blazor Web as with .Net Maui Blazor. I was trying to do this but it doesn't work. Any idea how I can switch what data service is called based on what's calling it?

```
@*@if(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.FriendlyName == "nu.web") 
{
    @inject IDataService _db
}
else
{
    @inject IHttpService _db
}*@
```

Thanks for any help...

Comment: you need to have an Interface which will expose requied methods for your controls. For this interface you will provide one implementation for blazor server and another implementation for Maui. In the implemented service you will inject what you need.

Comment: There are several ways to skin this cat.  Do they share the same interface?

Comment: They do share the same interface yes...

Comment: Thanks -Bennyboy1973 that was the clue I needed. I was thinking it needed to be done on the Blazor page. Just learning Blazor and loving it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Bennyboy1973’s hint… I removed the extra interface IHttpService and used IDataService on both HttpService and DataService.

Then on the .Net Blazor web app startup.cs file:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataService, DataService>();

Then on the .Net Maui Blazor app MauiProgram.cs file:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IDataService, HttpService>();

If anyone cares about why I wanted it this way…  I get a slight performance improvement from calling SQL via Dapper on web and .Net Maui doesn’t allow it… So I’m calling the same Dapper SQL via Minimal API.

Thanks again for all the answers

Comment: I haven't tried to make a Maui app yet, but I suspect when I do this exact scenario will come up immediately. You COULD also choose which particular implementation to use in a C#-style direct injection instead of using the `@inject` on a Blazor page. However, if they use different startup files, I think your solution is probably the best one anyway.